# Tomcat Unable to start while ruuning app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am using spring boot version 1.15 and facing above error while running app.

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>sendres</name>
<description>Spring Boot Project for Sendres</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.lang -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.stripes/stripes -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.stripes</groupId>
        <artifactId>stripes</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.htmlparser.jericho/jericho-html -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.htmlparser.jericho</groupId>
        <artifactId>jericho-html</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency> -->


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/javax.jms-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pingidentity</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentoken-agent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/opentoken-agent-2.5.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-pool/commons-pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jibx/jibx-run -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jibx-run</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jibx/jibx-bind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jibx-bind</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jibx/jibx-schema -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jibx-schema</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jibx-extras</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity-tools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.9</version>
    </dependency> -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <schemaBindingDirectory>src/main/java/jibx/xml/mappings/</schemaBindingDirectory>
                <includeSchemaBindings>
                    <includeSchemaBindings>*.xml</includeSchemaBindings>
                </includeSchemaBindings>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bind</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-plugin-apache-lang</id>
        <name>spring-plugin-apache-lang</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-plugin-oracle-jdbc</id>
        <name>spring-plugin-oracle-jdbc</name>
        <url>http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Getting Error:-

2018-06-27 14:52:00.662 ERROR 52260 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.gartner.SendresApplication.main(SendresApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:138) ~[spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:87) ~[spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:554) ~[spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179) ~[spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:114) ~[spring-boot-1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        ... 24 common frames omitted

Facing Issue after adding folling dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity-tools -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.9</version>
</dependency> -->
```

Comment: Suppose longer stack trace has interesting info

Comment: @JacekCz  added full stacktrace.

Comment: For starters stop mixing jars from different hibernate and spring versions... Your dependencies are a mess, manually including older versions of jar, mixing versions of frameworks. Clean up your pom first and where possible (mail, velocity, jpa etc. ) use the `spring-boot-starter` projects to get the spring managed versions.